Completeness preserved under specific homeomorphism
Problem: Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space, $(Y,d')$ a metric space, and $f\colon X\to Y$ a homeomorphism, such that there exists a $c>0$, for which $$c\cdot d(x,y)\leq d'(f(x), f(y)).$$ Show that $(Y,d')$ is complete.
Question: I'm not sure if I am overthinking it, but shouldn't the inequality be the other way around? In that case the problem seems clear to me.

The given condition is correct. Note that it means $f^{-1}$ is Lipschitz, and thus uniformly continuous, which is all we need. Indeed, let $(y_n)\subset Y$ be a Cauchy-sequence. Then $x_n:=f^{-1}(y_n)\subset X$, and by the completeness of $X$, we know $x_n\to x$. By the uniform continuity of $f^{-1}$ we then get $f(x_n)=y_n\to f(x)$, so $(y_n)$ is Cauchy and thus $(Y,d')$ is complete.
